# OSMDroid Offline map with zip from custom server

Tags: android, archive, offline, osmdroid

I'm having a really hard time to get OSMDroid working with our custom tile server. I'm getting our tiles in a zip file which has the following structure: 
ZoomLevel/Y/X

I've tried unzipping the zip to the osmdroid/tiles folder and the osmdroid/tiles/Mapnik folder but none of them seem work. I think I need to use the FileBasedTileSource but I don't know what to put in the aName and URL part of the method.

I'm trying to download specific areas as a zip file for use in offline situations, which on Google Maps works perfectly but I want to try out OSMDroid and see of the performance is better.

Can anyone give me some pointers on how to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Zip archives for osmdroid must have the following structure
{Source}/Z/X/Y.{extension}

Then tell osmdroid to use a tile source whose name matches exactly {Source}. Everything should be automatic.

Also, consider using sqlite database, they are generally faster

Comment: thx for your reply! The way the zip now is compressed server side is:
Z/X/Y/.png

How does one use OSMDroid with SQL database? Do I need to do this serverside aswell? Or can I do this on Android?

Comment: The still need the tile source name in the zip. More than one tile source can be in each zip. /source/z/x/y.png. If you're building the sqlite, just copy the sqlite file over /sdcard/osmdroid